# Http ответ по отправке нескольких файлов клиенту через сервер

Tags: http

Как должен выглядеть HTTP-ответ сервера после того как клиент сделал запрос на получение нескольких файлов? Возможно ли клиенту одним запросом получить из сервера  несколько файлов?

Comment: HTTP сервер отправляет один объект (файл) за сессию. Несколько файлов, это несколько запросов. Исключение составляет формат multipart-message, но его надо собирать в ручную, для сервера это все равно один файл при отправке.

Comment: NewView есть ли примеры multipart-message для отправки нескольких файлов клиенту?